# Depuis le temps

Tags: sens

I have heard the following dialogue in the TV series Marseille:

- A: Trois appels téléphoniques pour avoir un rendez-vous faut de la constance, huh?
- B: Ou plutôt une ambition dévorante.
- A: Tu me connais mal.
- B: Depuis le temps.

Context: Two politic adversaries arrange a meeting and have this dialogue when they finally meet.

What does "depuis le temps" mean here? "Since the time" makes no sense in English.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can translate it into English as *after all this time*.
It is an informal phrase that stresses that someone/something has been doing something or has been in a certain state for such a long time that one can have some expectations about it.

It can be used to shorten a longer phrase starting with "depuis le temps". In this case, it would be something like *depuis le temps qu'on se connait*.

Another example:

> Je n'ai pas besoin de t'expliquer les règles, tu les connais, depuis le temps.
>
> S'il était vraiment fou, ça se saurait, depuis le temps.
>
> C'était une star dans les années 80, mais depuis le temps, le public l'a oublié.